# EXC_BREAKPOINT when using UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, exception, crash, appdelegate

Yesterday Apple reviewed and accepted the submitted build of our app. 
Besides some issues that we could fix already there is one crash report that drives me crazy.

Here is the Fabric crash report stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              0xb7444 ForecastCollectionViewController.(locationHelper(didReceiveUpdatedLocationWithObjectID : NSManagedObjectID, finishedLoading : Bool) -> ()).(closure #1) (ForecastCollectionViewController.swift:82)
1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              0xb61d4 ForecastCollectionViewController.(locationHelper(didReceiveUpdatedLocationWithObjectID : NSManagedObjectID, finishedLoading : Bool) -> ()).(closure #1) (ForecastCollectionViewController.swift:1219)
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x23c27cbf _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x23c27cab _dispatch_client_callout + 22
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x23c2c559 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1532
5  CoreFoundation                 0x24057755 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
6  CoreFoundation                 0x24055c4f __CFRunLoopRun + 1590
7  CoreFoundation                 0x23fa41c9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
8  CoreFoundation                 0x23fa3fbd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
9  GraphicsServices               0x255c0af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
10 UIKit                          0x286dc435 UIApplicationMain + 144
11 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              0xd59c8 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x23c50873 (Missing)
```

The stack trace says the app crashes on line 82, which looks like that:

```
    lazy var appDelegate = {() -> AppDelegate in
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    }()
```

It also says that function locationHelper(didReceiveUpdatedLocationWithObjectID : NSManagedObjectID, finishedLoading : Bool) is the one calling app delegate which then causes the app to crash.

```
func locationHelper(didReceiveUpdatedLocationWithObjectID locationID: NSManagedObjectID, finishedLoading: Bool) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            guard let location = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext.objectWithID(locationID) as? LastVisited else {
                // Set updating status back to false
                self.updating = false
                // Stop refresh control animation
                self.stopRefreshControlAnimation(withSuccess: false) {
                    // Custom error
                    let errorDescription = NSLocalizedString("error", comment: "Show general error")

                    let errorMessage = Murmur(title: errorDescription, backgroundColor: Colors.sharedInstance.error, titleColor: .whiteColor(), font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13))
                    Whistle(errorMessage, action: .Present)
                }
                return
            }

            // Changes only made if is first loading action
            if self.isInitial {
                // Set tab bar active
                self.tabBarEnabled(active: true)
                // Set initial to false
                self.isInitial = false
            }

            // Append received location to current location variable
            self.currentLocation = location
            // Set search bar title
            var stringInSearchBar = "\(location.city)"
            if location.iso != "-" {
                stringInSearchBar = "\(stringInSearchBar), \(location.iso)"
            }
            var args = [String:AnyObject]()
            args[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.searchBar.setAttributedPlaceholder(stringInSearchBar, withAttributes: args)

            // Data changes
            if let data = location.offlineData {

                // Set new background if it has changed
                self.setBackgroundImage(withName: data.background!)
                // Set new background global variable
                GlobalSettings.sharedInstance.background = data.background!
                // Set new color model
                self.setColorModel(withPictocode: data.pictocode, daylight: data.daylight)
                print(data.pictocode)
                // Set last updated label
                self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
                self.dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
                self.dateFormatter.timeZone = nil
                self.refreshControlView.lastUpdatedLabel.text = self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(data.timestamp!)

                // Remove tab bar items if not available
                if let meta = data.meta {

                    // Check if tab bar controller has been passed in objects dic
                    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController, let currentControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
                        // Assign view controller array to local variable on initial start

                        var animated = true

                        var newViewControllers = [UIViewController]()
                        // Assign view controller array to local variable on initial start

                        let where2go = Where2GoViewController()
                        let wind = WindViewController()

                        newViewControllers.append(currentControllers[0])
                        newViewControllers.append(wind)
                        newViewControllers.append(where2go)

                        guard let satellite = meta.satelliteDomain, let radar = meta.radarDomain else {
                            // If not able to bind sat/rad values set standard views anyway
                            tabBarController.setViewControllers(newViewControllers, animated: true)
                            return
                        }

                        if satellite != "" {
                            let vc = SatelliteViewController()
                            newViewControllers.insert(vc, atIndex: 2)
                        }
                        if radar != "" {
                            let vc = RadarViewController()
                            if newViewControllers.count >= 4 {
                                newViewControllers.insert(vc, atIndex: 3)
                            } else {
                                newViewControllers.insert(vc, atIndex: 2)
                            }
                        }

                        if currentControllers.count == newViewControllers.count {
                            animated = false
                        }

                        tabBarController.setViewControllers(newViewControllers, animated: animated)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Reload collection view
            if self.collectionView!.dragging || self.collectionView!.decelerating {
                self.deferredReloading = true
            } else {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

            // Stop reload
            if finishedLoading {
                self.stopRefreshControlAnimation(withSuccess: true, completionHandler: nil)
            }

            // Set updating status back to false
            self.updating = false

            // Set location helper to nil
            self.locationHelper = nil

            // Save core data
            self.appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
    }
```

My two guesses are:

1. objectWithID in locationHelper(didReceiveUpdatedLocationWithObjectID locationID: NSManagedObjectID, finishedLoading: Bool) causes an exception that leads to the crash
2. Threading

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?